# A paper describes a past participle as “pure”, does anyone know the meaning?

Tags: past-participles

I read in a paper that the word loved is a “pure” past participle:

“*He was very loved. (Because loved is a past participle, very cannot be used to modify a pure past participle. Very much should be used.)
Cf. He was very much loved (by her).”

Can anybody explain the difference between a past participle and a “pure” one, please?

Comment: I don't think this is a standard grammatical term. Can you clarify in which paper you read it?

Comment: By the way, a simple online search in Google Books will show you that "he was very loved" is a perfectly acceptable phrase, used quite frequently.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the distinction between a past participle that is used only in the perfect, and one that is used as an adjective, like "broken" or "calculated" ("His strategy is very calculated")?

Comment: 'He was very much loved' is totally idiomatic. The 'past participle as **verb** form' ... '**adjective** as converted past participle' continuum has grey areas. And one will have to search harder for a true terminal example.

Comment: “The Use of Participles and Gerunds Wenyuan Gu West Career&Technical Academy Las Vegas, Nevada July 3, 2020” page twenty.

Comment: I agree with @StuartF — a past participle that doesn't play adjective. cf. *The food was enjoyed.*

Comment: Calling it "pure" is not a good thing for a scientist to do. It doesn't describe anything and it presupposes a hierarchical structure that doesn't exist.

Comment: I found the definition “pure” for a past participle in a paper. I thought it was peculiar, and that’s why I asked the question.